# Incomplete Parallel Mapping

Tags: list-manipulation, parallelization, coding-style

I am still struggling on how to nicely handle list operations in Mathematica, and perform simultaneously parallel computation. We consider a `tab` of the form

```
tab = {{x1,y1,z1},{x2,y2,z2},...,{xn,yn,zn}};
```

I know how to perform the following replacement

```
tab2 = tab /. {x_,y_,z_} -> {x,f[y_,z_]} ;
```

so that `tab2` is of the form

```
tab2 = {{x1,f[y1,z1]},{x2,f[y2,z2]},...,{xn,f[yn,zn]}};
```

However, because `f[y,z]` is an expensive function to compute, I would like to construct `tab2` in a parallel fashion. I tried using `ParallelMap`, but didn't find a neat way of performing the calculation, mainly because it requires to perform an *incomplete mapping*.

How should one proceed in order to build-up in parallel the second list `tab2` ? What would be the most efficient way to do it ?

Comment: how about `ParallelMap[{First[#], f @@ Rest[#]} &, tab]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
tab = Table[{x[n], y[n], z[n]}, {n, 4}]
```

> ```
> {{x[1], y[1], z[1]}, {x[2], y[2], z[2]},
>  {x[3], y[3], z[3]}, {x[4], y[4], z[4]}}
> ```

```
ParallelMap[{#, f[##2]} & @@ # &, tab]
```

> ```
> {{x[1], f[y[1], z[1]]}, {x[2], f[y[2], z[2]]},
>  {x[3], f[y[3], z[3]]}, {x[4], f[y[4], z[4]]}}
> ```

See [`Apply`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Apply.html) and [`SlotSequence`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SlotSequence.html) for clarification.

Answer (score 4):

Calling

```
tab = {{x1,y1,z1},{x2,y2,z2},{xn,yn,zn}};
```

We have

```
ParallelMap[{First[#], f @@ Rest[#]} &, tab]
```